# Solutioning - how to decide on the best architecture for your website or application?

Tags: architecture

I'm a newbie to architecture and solutioning.  I would like to know how to get started in this area.

Lets say I had a web site which would receive heavy traffic, had 200 forms, had a database of 200GB, how would I decide the best architecture and technology to use to create this web site?  Also the same question applies to a very large application.

How does one make these decisions and convince the user of the best technology that they should use?

Please let me know your thoughts, how to get started, if there are any articles I can read and more.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: +1 for good question but i think it'not related here it is in programmer.stackexchange or other , Please check :)

Answer (score 0):

The only piece of requirements mentioned here is

> ... which would receive heavy traffic, had 200 forms, had a database of 200GB

Unfortunately this is not nearly enough to provide a satisfactory answer.

I would only advise not be worried so much about choosing the "best technology". Spend some time really understanding requirements and work-flows. All "standard" technologies like Java, .NET, PHP, Python, Ruby, etc will do the job. Choose something that matches the skill set of your team. This would be a good start.

Comment: what if we have the luxury of choosing the team? i.e if we have all php, .Net and Java experts? what should be considered before settling for a particular technology.